# Cannnot open include file: `osg/Node`: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, openscenegraph

I don't know how I should ask this question. If I make any mistakes, I would appreciate it if someone could correct them.

I wrote a program in `Openscenegraph` from [OpenSceneGraph Tutorial](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//attachment/wiki/Support/Tutorials/NPS_Tutorials_src.rar) on `Microsoft Visual Studio` but when I press on Debugged, it gave error like this.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  GeometryTest.cpp
1>c:\osg\test\geometrytest.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'osg/Node': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am newbie for Openscenegraph and visual studio, but I don't have library called `Node`.

so please guide me on that what should I do to resolve this error?
Thank you

```
#include <osg/Node>
#include <osg/Group>
#include <osg/Geode>
#include <osg/Geometry>
#include <osg/Texture2D>
#include <osgDB/ReadFile> 
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>
#include <osg/PositionAttitudeTransform>
#include <osgGA/TrackballManipulator>
int main()
{
   osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
   osg::Group* root = new osg::Group();
   osg::Geode* pyramidGeode = new osg::Geode();
   osg::Geometry* pyramidGeometry = new osg::Geometry();
   osg::Geode* crossGeode = new osg::Geode();
   osg::Geometry* crossGeometry = new osg::Geometry();

   //Associate the pyramid geometry with the pyramid geode 
   //   Add the pyramid geode to the root node of the scene graph.

   pyramidGeode->addDrawable(pyramidGeometry); 
   root->addChild(pyramidGeode);
   crossGeode->addDrawable(crossGeometry); 
   root->addChild(crossGeode);

   //Declare an array of vertices. Each vertex will be represented by 
   //a triple -- an instances of the vec3 class. An instance of 
   //osg::Vec3Array can be used to store these triples. Since 
   //osg::Vec3Array is derived from the STL vector class, we can use the
   //push_back method to add array elements. Push back adds elements to 
   //the end of the vector, thus the index of first element entered is 
   //zero, the second entries index is 1, etc.
   //Using a right-handed coordinate system with 'z' up, array 
   //elements zero..four below represent the 5 points required to create 
   //a simple pyramid.

   osg::Vec3Array* pyramidVertices = new osg::Vec3Array;
   pyramidVertices->push_back( osg::Vec3( 0, 0, 0) ); // front left 
   pyramidVertices->push_back( osg::Vec3(10, 0, 0) ); // front right 
   pyramidVertices->push_back( osg::Vec3(10,10, 0) ); // back right 
   pyramidVertices->push_back( osg::Vec3( 0,10, 0) ); // back left 
   pyramidVertices->push_back( osg::Vec3( 5, 5,10) ); // peak

   float clen;
   clen = 12.0;
   osg::Vec3Array* crossVertices = new osg::Vec3Array;
   crossVertices->push_back (osg::Vec3(-clen, 0.0, 0.0));
   crossVertices->push_back (osg::Vec3( clen, 0.0, 0.0));
   crossVertices->push_back (osg::Vec3(  0.0, 0.0, -clen));
   crossVertices->push_back (osg::Vec3(  0.0, 0.0,  clen));  

   //Associate this set of vertices with the geometry associated with the 
   //geode we added to the scene.

   pyramidGeometry->setVertexArray( pyramidVertices );
   crossGeometry->setVertexArray (crossVertices);
   //Next, create a primitive set and add it to the pyramid geometry. 
   //Use the first four points of the pyramid to define the base using an 
   //instance of the DrawElementsUint class. Again this class is derived 
   //from the STL vector, so the push_back method will add elements in 
   //sequential order. To ensure proper backface cullling, vertices 
   //should be specified in counterclockwise order. The arguments for the 
   //constructor are the enumerated type for the primitive 
   //(same as the OpenGL primitive enumerated types), and the index in 
   //the vertex array to start from.

   osg::DrawElementsUInt* pyramidBase = 
      new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::QUADS, 0);
   pyramidBase->push_back(3);
   pyramidBase->push_back(2);
   pyramidBase->push_back(1);
   pyramidBase->push_back(0);
   pyramidGeometry->addPrimitiveSet(pyramidBase);

   osg::DrawElementsUInt* cross = 
      new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::LINES, 0);
   cross->push_back(3);
   cross->push_back(2);
   cross->push_back(1);
   cross->push_back(0);
   crossGeometry->addPrimitiveSet(cross);

   //Repeat the same for each of the four sides. Again, vertices are 
   //specified in counter-clockwise order. 

   osg::DrawElementsUInt* pyramidFaceOne = 
      new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::TRIANGLES, 0);
   pyramidFaceOne->push_back(0);
   pyramidFaceOne->push_back(1);
   pyramidFaceOne->push_back(4);
   pyramidGeometry->addPrimitiveSet(pyramidFaceOne);

   osg::DrawElementsUInt* pyramidFaceTwo = 
      new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::TRIANGLES, 0);
   pyramidFaceTwo->push_back(1);
   pyramidFaceTwo->push_back(2);
   pyramidFaceTwo->push_back(4);
   pyramidGeometry->addPrimitiveSet(pyramidFaceTwo);

   osg::DrawElementsUInt* pyramidFaceThree = 
      new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::TRIANGLES, 0);
   pyramidFaceThree->push_back(2);
   pyramidFaceThree->push_back(3);
   pyramidFaceThree->push_back(4);
   pyramidGeometry->addPrimitiveSet(pyramidFaceThree);

   osg::DrawElementsUInt* pyramidFaceFour = 
      new osg::DrawElementsUInt(osg::PrimitiveSet::TRIANGLES, 0);
   pyramidFaceFour->push_back(3);
   pyramidFaceFour->push_back(0);
   pyramidFaceFour->push_back(4);
   pyramidGeometry->addPrimitiveSet(pyramidFaceFour);

   //Declare and load an array of Vec4 elements to store colors. 

   osg::Vec4Array* colors = new osg::Vec4Array;
   colors->push_back(osg::Vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) ); //index 0 red
   colors->push_back(osg::Vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) ); //index 1 green
   colors->push_back(osg::Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) ); //index 2 blue
   colors->push_back(osg::Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) ); //index 3 white

   //Declare the variable that will match vertex array elements to color 
   //array elements. This vector should have the same number of elements 
   //as the number of vertices. This vector serves as a link between 
   //vertex arrays and color arrays. Entries in this index array 
   //coorespond to elements in the vertex array. Their values coorespond 
   //to the index in he color array. This same scheme would be followed 
   //if vertex array elements were matched with normal or texture 
   //coordinate arrays.
   //   Note that in this case, we are assigning 5 vertices to four 
   //   colors. Vertex array element zero (bottom left) and four (peak) 
   //   are both assigned to color array element zero (red).

   osg::TemplateIndexArray
      <unsigned int, osg::Array::UIntArrayType,4,4> *colorIndexArray;
   colorIndexArray = 
      new osg::TemplateIndexArray<unsigned int, osg::Array::UIntArrayType,4,4>;
   colorIndexArray->push_back(0); // vertex 0 assigned color array element 0
   colorIndexArray->push_back(1); // vertex 1 assigned color array element 1
   colorIndexArray->push_back(2); // vertex 2 assigned color array element 2
   colorIndexArray->push_back(3); // vertex 3 assigned color array element 3
   colorIndexArray->push_back(0); // vertex 4 assigned color array element 0

   //The next step is to associate the array of colors with the geometry, 
   //assign the color indices created above to the geometry and set the 
   //binding mode to _PER_VERTEX.

   pyramidGeometry->setColorArray(colors);
   pyramidGeometry->setColorIndices(colorIndexArray);
   pyramidGeometry->setColorBinding(osg::Geometry::BIND_PER_VERTEX);
   crossGeometry->setColorArray(colors);
   crossGeometry->setColorIndices(colorIndexArray);
   crossGeometry->setColorBinding(osg::Geometry::BIND_PER_VERTEX);

   //Now that we have created a geometry node and added it to the scene 
   //we can reuse this geometry. For example, if we wanted to put a 
   //second pyramid 15 units to the right of the first one, we could add 
   //this geode as the child of a transform node in our scene graph. 

   // Declare and initialize a transform node.
   osg::PositionAttitudeTransform* pyramidTwoXForm =
      new osg::PositionAttitudeTransform();

   // Use the 'addChild' method of the osg::Group class to
   // add the transform as a child of the root node and the
   // pyramid node as a child of the transform.

   root->addChild(pyramidTwoXForm);
   pyramidTwoXForm->addChild(pyramidGeode);

   // Declare and initialize a Vec3 instance to change the
   // position of the model in the scene

   osg::Vec3 pyramidTwoPosition(15,0,0);
   pyramidTwoXForm->setPosition( pyramidTwoPosition ); 

   //The final step is to set up and enter a simulation loop.

   viewer.setSceneData( root );
   //viewer.run();

   viewer.setCameraManipulator(new osgGA::TrackballManipulator());
   viewer.realize();

   while( !viewer.done() )
   {
      viewer.frame();
   } 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about *Visual Studio* project setup, than it is about *OSG*.

To be able to use a library, *Visual Studio* must know where to look for it.

In *Visual Studio 2013*, there are at least 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Right-click on your project -> Proeperties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories.
2. Right-click on your project -> Proeperties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

In both cases, you have to add the path to the osg include folder: `c:\DevTools\OpenSceneGraph\include\`. Do **not** append the `osg` folder to this path.

This is the way to add a library, for *OSG* and for other projects, so you'll need this procedure often.

You'll have do do something like that also for telling it where to look for your libraries (**.lib**):

1. Right-click on your project -> Proeperties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories
2. Right-click on your project -> Proeperties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

And you'll have to add the libraries to your project:

1. Right-click on your project -> Proeperties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies